# Very light blue screen overlay / tint on my macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

Sometimes I have a very light blue screen overlay (tint) on my Macbook Pro, not sure where it comes from or if it's from Apple (I have night shift disabled).

I wanted to take a picture but it disappeared. I will add a picture if it appears again as it appears quite randomly. Sometimes it goes away when I remove my charger then it comes back.

Comment: Without actually seeing it, it's impossible to accurately diagnose.  You'll have to have a camera ready to capture it especially when you take it in for service.  But for now, to try and rule out software, start by booting in  [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  If it continues, try a clean install of macOS on an external USB drive (a 32GB flash is fine as it's for diagnostics).  If it continues, it's hardware.  **What specific MacBook Pro and version of macOS are you using?**  Please [edit] your question with the details/results.

Comment: Take a photo and a screenshot & compare the two on another screen or computer, as well as posting here

Comment: Perhaps try disabling True Tone, if that's an option

Comment: thanks @Hefewe1zen, disabling true tone actually makes the tint blue so not sure what i should do

Comment: It could be a hardware issue then.  I had a similar problem but with my iPhone display.  Suggest bringing it in to Applet to see what they say, if its under warranty should be covered repair.