# Slight blue shade on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, display, color

[image: on mymac]

I am seeing a [light blue shade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/405770/5472) on anything I open in my MacBook, it just started suddenly and I don’t have any idea why its happening. The image above shouldn’t have a blue cast.

Is there a sequence of things to check when the color looks off unexpectedly? [image]

Answer (score 4):

This is either a colour profile or possibly a hardware issue.
It may also be a [True Tone](https://support.apple.com/HT208909) or [Night Shift](https://support.apple.com/HT207513) issue [though I've never had a Mac that can use those so I've no experience with them].

Your screenshot does not show any colour cast at all and 'white is white', as in this image showing the Digital colour meter over your screenshot (whether or not you see it that way, that's what the numbers say.)

> [image]

First check the Apple KB links above to make sure it's not True Tone/Night Shift.
If neither of those is the cause, then either someone/something has changed your screen profile… or you have a hardware issue.
System Prefs > Display > Colour
Check what profile is shown as in use.
Check other profiles to see if they all show a similar colour-cast - some will look OK & some will look awful, but you need to determine if it's always 'too blue'.

If most profiles show the colour is 'balanced' if not 'good' then you could try re-calibrating your display by eye.
To the right of that control panel is Calibrate…
Hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  as you click it & it will open with the Advanced parameters as an option. Check 'Expert Mode' & work your way through the following screens, adjusting each as best you can all the way through.

If all your efforts come out blue no matter what you do, then suspect a hardware fault & take it to Apple.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer.. I checked its not True Tone/night shift. so when am checking in display profile, there are so many, when I click on them they keep on changing colours, but none restores back the normal one. can you check again I have taken a photo from the phone, this will explain better, now it has changed to a pinkish shade. I tried to calibrate, putting in the white shade, but again the shade comes back.

Comment: I did say that the ones in the list would go from 'OK' to 'Horrible' - this was to establish whether the blue always dominated. The photo from your phone looks to have no blue cast at all. It also looks like you didn't revert to the original profile nor did you run the manual calibration. It looks like you just took a picture of a 'random' profile. Can you run the calibration & then take another photo.